# Cannot pass URL in PHP GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, get

When going to `http://foo.com/bar.php?url=http://foobar.com/` I get a `403 Forbidden` error.
The same happens if I encode the URL: `http://foo.com/bar.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoobar.com%2F`

But if I encodes it twice, it will work: `http://foo.com/bar.phpurl=http%253A%252F%252Ffoobar.com%252F`

I know I can do this, but it's really annoying.

I have tried to add the following line to .htaccess: `SecFilterEngine Off`

It doesn't matter if `bar.php`, exist or is empty, it will still display 403 Forbbidden.

But, I then get the error: `Invalid command 'SecFilterEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: do you have a link to your httpd.conf or .htaccess? Are you sure your mod_security.c is loaded with the correct parameters?
http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/03-configuration.html

Comment: What is your concrete question? What do you want to do? Please add the code of `bar.php` to your question.

Comment: I don't have root access to the website, so I don't even know if I have mod_security

Comment: @Tyilo: try to look at my answer...

Comment: @hakre: the code for bar.php does not matter at all. In the question OP specified that it does not matter whether bar.php exist or not.

Comment: @Salman A: Then probably you can explain what the actual question is? What's to be achieved? What is the concrete problem? I thought it would be easier to understand when looking into the code, however as you're having more information, this might not be necessary any longer and you can say. So please share the information you have.

Comment: @tyilo: does apache give you more information apart from *403 forbidden* header? what does the content of the page say? and can you post relevant entries from access/error log?

Comment: @hakre: it could be a server configuration error.

Comment: @Salman A: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /bar.php on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the error:
"Invalid command 'SecFilterEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included"

It is because you have not included the ":LoadModule security_module modules/mod_security.so" in the httpd.conf.

Another posible reason is that you are using mod_security2 and the SecFilterEngine is obsolete and you should migrate it to SecRuleEngine as is explained in the migration document.

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/ModSecurity-Migration-Matrix.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is [solution](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/4e2fd.php) in PHP.

You can keep it encoded twice and decode it twice

```
<?php 
echo rawurldecode(rawurldecode("http://foo.com/bar.php?url=http%253A%252F%252Ffoobar.com%252F"));
```